# How to hide unused columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to make a Google Spreadsheet that has a limited column numbers but I cannot find where is this configured. Looked for this setting with all that I could think would make a good keyword : "Limit google sheets columns", "Google Sheets, hide unused columns" but without luck.

If you look at the to-do template you will notice that the columns goes up to C and not to "Infinite":

[image]

How can I achieve this on a newly created sheet ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To complete Jacob Jan Tuinstra answer and after some research I found out that it was easier than one initially thinks. Just delete the columns manually.

### How ?

Select form the last unused to the Z and then right click on a column header and then click on delete columns. Voila.

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

There's a fantastic *Add-on* for this created by Googler **[Eric Koleda](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+EricKoleda/posts)**:

[image]

### References

- **[Crop Sheet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/crop-sheet/aojcceglbipehndciapjedoomockgagl?utm_source=permalink)**
- **[Github code](https://github.com/erickoledadevrel/crop-sheet/)**